# django imagekit - compress and resize on condition

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-imagekit

I am new to django. I am struggling to write the code for django imagekit which checks if the image is of a certain size and of certain dimension then compress or resize or do both at the same time.

I have read about processors and defining ImageSpec but I am confused as to how to get this done :((

I have defined ProcessedImageField() in ModelForm

just struggling with how to write the code for processors.

Comment: I wrote a response to the other question you posted on the topic, use os.stat to get the image size in bytes.

Comment: Thanks, I have used it but it gives an error.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641051/django-imagekit-and-pil